# Should I allow users to save their passwords?

Tags: security, cookies

Currently on our web-based apps we don't allow users to save their login information. The login itself is simply a secure cookie with a random hash which points to session information on the back end. There are no issues like HIPAA to be had, we just never implemented saving credentials, because it doesn't seem like a good idea to me.

What are the pros and cons from a security perspective on this? I worry about users getting saved cookies taken, though we do check session against IP address as well. I just don't want to miss anything.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “we don’t allow users to save their login information”?

Comment: Well, being a web-based app, something along the lines of "Remember my password" checkbox.

Comment: http://fishbowl.pastiche.org/2004/01/19/persistent_login_cookie_best_practice/ - even though this is old, it's still a very good read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never 'save' the credentials, always generate a secure token that you will store on the client side and treat it as if it was the user's password (it kind of is, actually).

But first:

- High value applications MUST NOT possess remember me functionality.
- Medium value applications SHOULD NOT contain remember me functionality. If present, the user MUST opt-in to remember me. The system SHOULD strongly warn users that remember me is insecure particularly on public computers
- Low value applications MAY include an opt-in remember me function. There should be a warning to the user that this option is insecure, particularly on public computers.

Always give the user an overview of active sessions once he is logged in and give him the option to terminate certain sessions.

You could use this strategy described [here as best practice](http://jaspan.com/improved_persistent_login_cookie_best_practice):

1. When the user successfully logs in with Remember Me checked, a **login cookie is issued** in addition to the standard session management cookie.
2. The login cookie contains the user's **username, a series identifier, and a token**. The series and token are **unguessable random numbers** from a suitably large space. All three are stored together in a database table.
3. When a non-logged-in user visits the site and presents a login cookie, the username, series, and token are **looked up in the database**.

   1. If the **triplet is present**, the user is considered **authenticated**. The used **token is removed** from the database. A **new token** is generated, stored in database with the username and the same series identifier, and a new login cookie containing all three is issued to the user.
   2. If the username and series are present but the token does not match, a **theft** is assumed. The user receives a strongly worded warning and all of the user's remembered sessions are deleted.
   3. If the username and series are not present, the login cookie is **ignored**.

Comment: This is essentially what I had in mind. Since it's the best approach, I guess there's nothing wrong with wanting to do it that way. I was uncertain whether or not it was a good idea *period*.